# High CPU load using VideoCapture (OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code, cpu-usage, putty

**EDIT**: I was using SSH Remote connection to headless server via VSCode.
When I am using PuTTy to connect the server remotely, the CPU usage is below than the one with using VSCode! Therefore, the problem might be initiating with VSCode. Here is PuTTy CPU usage of this code:
[image]

**Actual Question Starts:**

I have a CPU problem while reading and writing frames from IP camera:

**What should be the problematic in this code snippet which results in high CPU overload?**

*Here are I am suspecting to be the reason of CPU overload:*

- CPU usage result in the lowermost figure is from VSCode SSH Remote Connection to a headless server. When I am using PuTTy for remote connection, this code is not piling up the CPU.
- 1920x1080 streaming without decreasing FPS of stream (`which is 25`)
- Image resizing function of OpenCV
- fourcc Codec choice (`.mp4` is chosen)
- Stream FPS and Desired FPS unmatching (`Stream:25 , Desired FPS: 1/60` )
- Using headless server (I cannot show images due to this but i am not sure this might be the reason)

*Things I tried to slow down CPU usage but did not work well:*

- `time.sleep(0.1)`
- `cv.waitKey(1000*int(0.1*(1/fps))`

```
    import os
    import cv2 as cv
    import numpy as np
    import time
    import math
    from datetime import datetime
    import re
    
    cap = cv.VideoCapture('rtsp://**.***.**.*:*****/************',cv.CAP_FFMPEG)
         
    def frameNaming():
      today = datetime.now()
      date1 = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
      abc = re.findall(r'\d+',date1)
      frameName = ''.join(abc)
      return frameName
    
    down_height = 720
    down_width = 1280
    down_points = (down_width, down_height)
    
    fpsSystem = cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    print("Fps of System",fpsSystem)
    frameRead       = 0             # successfully readed frame number
    fps = 1.0/60
    print("Desired FPS of video",fps)
    DesFrameCount =  60 # Desired frame count
    print("Desired Frame Number in Video: %.1f"%(DesFrameCount))
    takeFrameTime = 1/fps # every TakeFrameTime seconds frames will be stored
    
    frameCycle      = 0             # every frameCycle. frame will be stored
    frameWritten = 0
    firstStart = time.time()
    start=firstStart
    print("First Start Time",firstStart)
    print("time", frameNaming())
    success = True
    # Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
    fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
    randomName = np.random.randint(0,1000)
    out = cv.VideoWriter('output'+str(randomName) + "_60min_.mp4", fourcc, fps, (down_width,  down_height))

    while success:   
        success, frame = cap.read()
        #time.sleep(0.1)
        if not success:
            print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
            break
        else:
            frameRead += 1
            frameCycle += 1
        frame = cv.resize(frame,down_points,interpolation= cv.INTER_AREA)

        if frameCycle == math.floor(fpsSystem*takeFrameTime): # Stop the loop when desired number of Frame obtained
            frameCycle  = 0
            out.write(frame)
            frameWritten += 1
            timeNow = frameNaming()
            datenow = timeNow[:-6]
            hournow = timeNow[-6:]
            print("Frame written Time", hournow)
        if  (cv.waitKey(1000*int(0.1*(1/fps))) & 0xFF == ord('q')) or (frameWritten == DesFrameCount):
            print("Curr Time")
            print("stop Time",time.time()-firstStart)
            print("firstStart",firstStart)
            print("Read Frame Count",frameRead)
            print("Written Frame Count",frameWritten)
            print("Frame written Date", datenow)
            break
    # Release everything if job is finished
    cap.release()
    out.release()
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is the CPU load:

[image: CPU load]

Comment: which part of that code causes how much cpu?

Comment: WaitKey seems to be holding the thread for 6s.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, How can i check it?

Comment: waitkey uses almost no CPU, it mostly sleeps. if using 80 cores is the issue, waitKey isn't the cause. -- use `time.perf_counter()` in various places, then take differences.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, thank you for your reply, I used `time.perf_counter()` and saw that resizing, different fps VideoWrite and Codec choice seem not be a problem, those all take up to milliseconds level. Now, CPU usage is somehow decreased to reasonable levels, but idk how still. It might be originated from server.

Comment: if this only happens when you run the code with VSC, then maybe you accidentally caused it to start the python code in a debugging mode, so it's doing whatever amount of extra work... -- voting to close as *not reproducible*. if you still need this solved, please work to present a [mre]. determine if involvement of RTSP is required to cause this (because setting up an RTSP source is probably the largest effort for anyone in trying to reproduce this). basic debugging/differential diagnosis.

Comment: RTSP is also not a problem for high CPU usage right now according to current streaming is working without high CPU usage.
Now, should I delete the question to close it or edit/answer the question as not reproducible? @ChristophRackwitz

Comment: I guess you should leave it here, in case anyone else finds it. you _did_ figure out that it must have something to do with vscode over ssh and running your program through it